# Chatting on three or four computers via LAN cables

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, socket.io, localserversocket

I have made a **chat App** using **node.js** and **Soket.Io**. To use my chat App you just enter your name and then you can start chatting. I can chat by two names in differrent browser of my computer. Now I want to connect three-four computers of my friends via **LAN-CABLES** and then use this chat App to chat. **Can someone help me how to do this? How to carry out this whole process?**

Comment: The same way you do in the two browsers just instead of localhost you use the ip of the computer running the node.js app (just make sure your firewall is not blocking it)

Comment: They also need to be connected to a switch, hub or router with appropriate IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to give the ip address of Lan to your friends,and when they put in the browser.it works.For that just need small networking..